# export piwik report: height of iframe

Tags: iframe, height, matomo

I want to add some applications which show statistics of my site..
The embed code that piwik gives me is something like

```
<div id="widgetIframe"><iframe width="100%" height="350" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/apps/piwik/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Live&actionToWidgetize=widget&idSite=1&period=day&date=today&disableLink=1&widget=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>
```

The problem is that sometimes height of iframe is bigger than piwik suggest me to embed..
Some other time the height is less..
How can i solve this problem?
i write `height="auto"` with no luck

Any suggestion?

Edit: Note that i try this in localhost, but piwik (and also the iframe) is installed into my real site..

Edit2: This lines of code solve the problem http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/

Still problem: **if the content inside the iframe changes height, this won't adapt**

Comment: Anyone can help me?
Any jquery plugin?